# Dispensing items free for restricted purposes

Tags: england-and-wales, any-jurisdiction

Suppose a grocery chain charges £0.3 for carrier bags but gives out smaller and slightly flimsier ones for free, but they are imagined as only to be used for fresh produce to be weighed.

Bob sees them and decides he would prefer to use one of these for his packaged grocery purchases rather than pay £0.3 for a sturdier type of bag.

An employee sees Bob putting his shopping into a produce bag and tells him off that they are only for fruits and vegetables. Is it possible to give out something for free but require that it not be used for certain purposes?

Comment: Alternate version of the same question: is a grocery store allowed to let people use shopping carts for free, but then tell Bob he can't take the wheels off the cart for a craft project?

Comment: I think I’d beg to differ. In that case there is being granted a temporary license to use the shopping cart. In my question the produce bags are intended to be kept by Bob permanently.

Comment: Feel free to switch it up as appropriate: Is a grocery store allowed to let people use toilet paper in its bathroom for free, but then tell Bob he can't take the roll home with him?

Comment: Idk, what if he just uses it to blow his nose instead of to wipe his bum? Or what if he has the sniffles and puts a bunch into his pocket for the rest of the afternoon until he gets home?

Comment: I guess I'm surprised at the suggestion that the distinctions here are too nuanced. In any event, @msalters has correctly answered the question below.

Answer (score 1):

These flimsy bags are not given out for free. They're included at no additional charge with qualified purchases (specifically fresh produce to be weighed).

It's like a "buy two X, get a third one free". You can't just take one X and claim it's still free. Bob needs to first buy something in order to get something for free.

If you buy two kiwis, get a bag for them, and proceed to eat the kiwis, you'll own an empty bag. It doesn't matter exactly when you eat these kiwis, this could even be directly after paying for them. And what you do with your bag is up to you.

Comment: This read would seem problematic as from Bob’s perspective he was simply perusing the isles of the store, sees a bunch of times with price tickets attached to them, and then these bags all in a dispenser with no price tag attached. For items that are properly buy x get y free, those terms are clearly indicated. They seem more akin to the loo rolls in the dispensers in the toilet, or the paper towels in there by the sink which nobody will mind if you go in to the toilet and take whether it is for wiping a spill on your shirt or for drying your hands after washing them having used the toilet.

Comment: I think anyone who has been to a grocery store ever in their lives would say this seems not problematic at all. Why is Bob unable to handle a situation that millions of other people navigate every day without any confusion? Are you just asking whether Bob -- by virtue of being a complete idiot -- gets a pass on stealing things?

Comment: If I had to guess then I’d venture that its rather because he enjoys questioning the ambiguous aspects of things when it’s usually big corps that use those to screw over every day people.

Comment: But no, I’m asking as to the actual legal position of the “things” in the first place

Comment: @bdb484 Complete idiots are a common occurrence in retail.

Answer (score -1):

The owner of a thing can put conditions on how you can come to be the owner of their thing, even if they will be gifting it to you.

In this case, the store has informed Bob that they are not gifting the bag to Bob unless the bag is holding produce to the till.

Once the bag is Bob's, however, Bob can do what Bob wants with it.